# Jenkins pipeline doesn't recognise my Angular project

Tags: angular, linux, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project with a more complex structure that I'm working on, like this:
'rootFolder/frontendParentFolder/actualAngularProject'

I have a Jenkins job that tries to run the code coverage task for the angular project.

The step that I have right now is like this:

```
stage('Testing Front End') {
              steps {
                  echo 'Running front end tests...'
                  dir('frontendParentFolder/actualAngularProject') {
                        sh 'ng test --code-coverage --watch=false'
                  }
              }
}
```

The Jenkins job does checkout and build and other stuff, it obviously starts from the root of the project. When it gets to this step it says this ...

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Testing Front End)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Running front end tests...
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/jenkins/workspace/rootFolder/frontendParentFolder/actualAngularProject
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[actualAngularProject] Running shell script
+ ng test --code-coverage --watch=false
The test command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
```

I tried also mentioning the name of the project like sh 'ng test actualAngularProject --code-coverage --watch=false' , but I still get the same thing.
I tried to install the NPM plugin, but I didn't know how to use it and didn't find a proper example for it.

I have:
Jenkins ver. 2.222.3;
Angular CLI: 8.3.18;
Node: 12.13.0;
OS: linux x64

If I try to run the same command from CLI, it works. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: For debugging purpose just add `ls -al` and see you are running the command against correct directory or not. if not try to add $WORKSPACE environment variable to navigate to you expected dicrectory with dir() DSL - `dir("${env.WORKSPACE}/your/path")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is correct, the only thing is: You might miss the actual path of the angular project folder.
my below example, illustrate something similar to your example and will help you to debug and find your root cause

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage("create folder & file for debug") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
                sh """
                    mkdir -p a/b/c
                    echo "Hello , I am from folder C" >> a/b/c/c.txt
                """    
            }
        }
        stage("debug") {
            steps {
                sh """
                    ls -al a
                    ls -al a/b
                    ls -al a/b/c
                    cat a/b/c/c.txt
                """
                
                dir('a/b/c') {
                    sh "cat c.txt"
                }
                
                // or
                
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}/a/b/c") {
                    sh "cat c.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by debugging as you suggested. Found the problem and resolved it. It was running in the wrong folder because I was pointing at the wrong folder which seemed to be OK at the beginning.
So it was basicaly my problem, by pointing to a similar folder.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read the stack overflow instructions correctly to make use of . You have added a comment in answer - which is not correct. If you feel the answer i gave was correct you should accept it so that other can benefit from that as well !